# C++ : use current instance (object) in function

Tags: c++, function, object, instance

**Greetings C++ community !**

*I am new to C++ i have this code example :*

```
class Player
{
 public:
  int pdamage;
  int phealth;
 /* ... other data members and some void member functions (getName etc.) */
};

class Ennemy
{
 public:
  int edamage;
  int ehealth;
}; 

**/*here i would like to use current objects parameters for calculation and return to current player instance(current player object) the health value.*/**


int playerHit(this.Player.damage,this.Enemy.ehealth)
{
 ehealth = this.Ennemy.ehealth - this.Player.damage;
 return ehealth;
};

int ennemyHit(this.Player.phealth,this.Enemy.edamage)
{
 phealth = this.Player.phealth - this.Ennemy.edamage ;
 return ehealth;
};

int main()
{
/*....*/

return 0;
}
```

**Returning to the post question:** 
*How i use current object parameters in a function for calculations?*

/*Since i am new to stackoverflow and C++ Thanks for all advises and suggestions and critics ! */

Comment: `int playerHit(this.Player.damage,this.Enemy.ehealth)` not C++ code, doesn';t match syntax rules

Comment: Your code is very wrong. You should go back to a good book/tutorial about C++, especially the parts where it talks about classes.

Comment: in Java as i recall you can use this to reference for current object ,in C++ this is a pointer and * also is a pointer. Thats why in my head there are intereferences ,that is why i went to you guys ,to understand.

Comment: Sorry to say, but C++ is nothing like Java. There is no way to write a C++ program by guessing the syntax. You have to read up on how it works and can find [some good books here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: guys i know all that,go back to books etc. I prefer to code ,and learn by mistakes.

Comment: I think you wanna pass the objects of these two classes to the function. Since you have declared everything `public`, I think this might be the thing:   `int playerHit(const Player& P, const Enemy& E)
  {
    return E.ehealth - P.pdamage;
  };`. And of-course,  learn the basics before try something like this.

Comment: JeJo thx for great answer i start to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you would pass the calles either as pointer or reference

```
int playerHit(const Player& player, const Ennemy& ennemy)
{
     return ennemy.ehealth - player.pdamage;
};
```

Comment: The variable is pdamage